# NSTask - execute echo command

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, command, nstask

I'm trying to run a simple **task which has to execute an echo** "Hello World"

Well here is my *code:*

```
NSTask *task;
    task = [[NSTask alloc] init];


    [task setLaunchPath:@"/bin/bash"]; 




    NSArray *arguments;

    arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"echo","hello world" nil];
    [task setArguments: arguments];

    NSPipe *pipe;
    pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    [task setStandardOutput: pipe];
    [task setStandardError: pipe];

    NSFileHandle *file;
    file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];



    [task launch];
    //...
    //Code to get task response
```

Keep giving me ***no such file or directory error***.. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Why are you trying to have the shell do this? One of the advantages of NSTask is not having to go through the shell. You can run the echo command (the stand-alone version, not bash's) directly.

Comment: @Peter Hosey Care to post how you can run the echo command through NSTask stand alone ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way to execute a command is

```
bash -c "echo 'hello world'"
```

which means the arguments you should pass are

```
arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-c", @"echo 'hello world'", nil];
```